# Insert json object in mysql DB with Mule ESB

Tags: mysql, json, string, mule

Good evening!

I’m trying to insert an entire json object into mysql table. I’m using json to object transformer to convert json into HashMap. Json is this:

```
    {
   "content": {
      "fill": "none",
      "stroke": "#fff",
      "path": [
        ["M", 422, 115],
        ["L", 472, 167.5]
      ],
      "stroke-width": 4,
      "stroke-linecap": "round",
      "stroke-linejoin": "round",
      "transform": [],
      "type": "path",
      "note": {
        "id": 47,
        "page":0, 
        "ref": 3,
        "txt": "teste do serviço",
        "addedAt": 1418133743604,
        "addedBy": "valter.gomes"
      }
  }
}
```

I need insert "content" object, but when I try access it by `#[payload.content]`, threws an exception :

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr...' for column 'content' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

We found what I think is a workaround. Before convert into a HashMap I get "content" object into a variable `#[json:content]` and record it in DB `#[flowVars.rawContent]`. When I  retrive it from DB I convert ResultSet into String using Object to String converter.

But, Im not confortable with this solution. Is this the right way to do so? Or does exist other one ?  Maybe the right one.

Tks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the json you can transform to Map class (By default json:json-to-object-transformer return JsonData). For that reason I have specified Map class. So, after that you can read content from payload using `#[payload.content]`

I attached my flow:

```
<flow name="demoFlow1" doc:name="demoFlow1">     
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8081" path="demo" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
       <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
            Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map1.put("fill","none");
            map1.put("stroke","#fff");  
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("content", map1);
            return map;]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message=">>1 #[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>     
    <set-payload value="#[payload.content]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message=">>3 #[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Tks Eddú for replay..i tried this out and worked well..i was receiving that exception because of the field type in mysql. To solve this I changed my database to postgresql, which has support for json type.

Comment: It is not about reputation, it's about was useful and help yo solve your answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Eddú is right, but the example he gives is really too complex.

As he said, all you need is:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" />
```

After that transformer, you can retrieve any field/sub-field in the Map. I suggest using `message.payload` instead of `payload` by the way, the latter has shown some odd behaviours in the past.

So use: `#[message.payload.content]`

Also, this will give you an object of type `java.util.Map`. Not sure how you're going to insert the object in the DB but since you are not showing this part in your question, I imagine you'll figure it out...

Comment: Tks a lot for your help David Dossot...I used Map and worked..as I already commented, to insert in DB I used postgresql, which has native support. Tks also for the tips... refactoring the code.